# words processing (dynamic array of structs)

Tags: arrays, dynamic, input, struct, counter

//runs through initial values and set them to null and zero;

```
for(int g =0;g<Arraysize;g++){Array1[g].word="NULL";Array1[g].usage=0;}
//struct

    int Arraysize = 100;
    struct HeavyWords{
    string word;
    int usage;
    };
    //runs through txt file and checks if word has already been stored, if it didn't, 
    it adds it as the next point in the struct, if it has, it adds to the usage int at that point in my array of structs
    while (myfile >> Bookword)
            {totalwords++;cout<<Bookword<<endl;
                bool foundWord = false;
                for(int q = 0;q<counter;q++)
                {
                   if(Array1[q].word == Bookword)
                    {
                        Array1[q].usage++;
                        foundWord = true;
                    }
                }

                if(foundWord == false) {
                    Array1[counter].word = Bookword;
                    Array1[counter].usage = 1;
                    counter++;
                    //cout<<counter<<endl;
                }
    //double size of array when the counter reaches array size
                if(counter==Arraysize)
                {
                    HeavyWords * Array2;
                    Array2  = new HeavyWords[2*Arraysize];
                    for (int k= 0;k<Arraysize;k++)
                    {
                        Array2[k].word = Array1[k].word;
                    }
                    Arraysize = 2*Arraysize;
                    Arraydouble++;
                    HeavyWords* cursor = Array1;
                    Array1 = Array2;
                    delete [] cursor;
                }
            }
```

//I just started programming in C++ so im apologize if this code is an explosion of nonesence.
//here is my code, 
//I have been racking my brain as to why it is not correctly storing the usage of each word, but when I run it, it gives me the incorrect amount of times certain words are used
//would really love if someone could tell me where my logic went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Immediate problem - While copying Array1 to Array2 you are not copying the usage.

Solution - copy the usage. A statement such as  Array2[k] = Array1[k] would do.

*Suggestions*:

You are also not breaking out in the first part of the code when you find a match in the Array1 for the word you are looking for. You code would needlessly continue to iterate over the entire array, when e.g. a match would have been found at say 10th index and you could have come out of the for loop.

You are re inventing the wheel. You need an expandable array; C++ STL has one readymade for you - it is called vector.

Also Array/Vector does NOT look to be right choice for what you are trying to do. On each word you are doing a linear search on the Array1. A map from C++ STL would neatly AND efficiently do what you are trying to do. Your code would also be much shorter. You can look up on how to code with maps. If you write some code, I can help further. Or wait; someone here would write out entire code for you :).

Comment: vundebar, switching the middle piece of the array doubling loop got the rest of my code working, and thanks for the heads up on the break statement. unfortunately not allowed to use vectors =(. any who thanks for the expert view it is much appreciated.

Comment: If it was a assignment, that forbade using vectors, then also it is a bad assignment. It is teaching you bad programming - using a unsuitable data structure for the problem at hand.